# Mediafilesegmenter inserts timed metadata ID3 tags in HLS stream but at the wrong point in time

Tags: id3, m3u8, http-live-streaming

I am inserting timed metadata in a HLS (HTTP Live Stream) using id3taggenerator and mediafilesegmenter. I have followed the instructions from [Jake's Blog](https://jmacmullin.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/adding-meta-data-to-video-in-ios/).

First, I create the id3tag using id3taggenerator:

```
id3taggenerator -o text.id3 -t "video"
```

Then add the tag to the `id3macro` file:

```
0 id3 /path/to/file/text.id3
```

And segment the video and insert the id3 tags with mediafilesegmenter:

```
mediafilesegmenter -M /path/to/id3macro -I -B "my_video" video.mp4
```

However, the timed metadata is inserted at the wrong point in time. Instead of showing up at the beginning of the video (point in time 0), it is added with a delay of 10 s (give or take 0.05 seconds, sometimes more, sometimes less).

I've wrote a simple iOS player app that logs whenever it is notified of an id3 tag in the video. The app is notified after playing the video for around 10 seconds of the ID3 tag. I've also tried with another id3macro file, with multiple timed metadata inserted in the video (around 0s, 5s, 7s), all showing up with the same approximate delay. I have also changed with the duration of the segment to 5s, but each time it's the same result.

The `mediafilesegmenter` I am using is `Beta Version 1.1(140602)`.

Can anyone else confirm this problem, or pin-point to what am I doing wrong here?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that I experience the same issue, using the same version of mediafilesegmenter:

mediafilesegmenter: Beta Version 1.1(140602)

Moreover, I can see that the packet with ID3 is inserted in the right moment in the stream. Eg. if I specify a 10 second delay – I can see that my ID3 is inserted in the end of the first 10 second segment.

However, it appears 10 seconds later in iOS notifications.

I can see the following possible reasons:

- mediafilesegmenter inserts metadata packet in the right place, but timestamp is delayed by 10 seconds for some reason. Therefore, clients (eg. iOS player) show the tag 10 seconds later. Apple tools are not well documented so it's hard to verify.
- Maybe iOS player receives metadata in time (because I know the tag was included in previous segment file) but issues a notification with 10 second delay, for whatever reason.

I cannot dig further because I don't have any Flash/desktop HLS players that support in-stream ID3 tags. If I had one, I would check whether desktop player will display/process ID3 in time, without delay. Then, it would mean the problem is iOS, not mediafilesegmenter.

Another useful thing to do would be – extracting MPEG-TS frame with ID3 tag from the segment file, and checking headers, looking for any strange things there (eg. wrong timestamp).

Update:

I did some more research including reverse engineering of TS segments created with Apple tools, and it seems:

- mediafilesegmenter starts PTS (presentation time stamps) from 10 seconds while, for example, ffmpeg starts from 0.
- mediafilesegmenter adds ID3 frame at the correct place in TS file but with wrong PTS that is 10 seconds ahead of what was specified in meta file.

While the first issue doesn't seem to affect the playback (as far as I understand it's more important that PTS goes on continuously, not where it starts), the second is definitely an issue and the reason you/we are experiencing the problem.

Therefore, iOS player receives ID3 frame in time but since its PTS is 10 seconds ahead – it waits 10 seconds before issuing a notification. As far as I can say now – some other players simply ignore this ID3 frame because it's in the wrong place.

As a workaround, you can shift all ID3 files by 10 seconds in your meta file, but obviously, you won't be able to put anything in the beginning.

Comment: Because of the bug in Apple tools, and because the tools run only under OS X, I had to write my own metadata injector: https://github.com/dusterio/hlsinjector  Feel free to use it :) I tested it in production environment already